# Nested where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary of users   `Dictionary<String, User> usersBase`

Each user has a list of ratings `List<UserRating> ratings`. Each rating contains a string for the movie id and a rating.

```
class UserRating
{
        private String movieId;
        private int rating;
}
```

I'm trying to get the list of users who has rated a specific id like this

```
List<User> commun = new List<User>();
commun = usersBase.Values.Where(x => x.Ratings.Where(y => y.MovieId == movieId)).ToList();
```

I have the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'

Could anyone explain to me how to do this and why I have this error?

Comment: Be sure to mark an answer if one of them works for you.

Comment: Yeah I had to go before I could mark the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.Where` expects a lambda that returns a bool. Your nested where clause returns an IEnumerable instead.

Try this instead:

```
 commun = usersBase.Values.Where(x => x.Ratings.Any(y => y.MovieId == movieId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<User> commun = new List<User>();
commun = usersBase.Values.Where(x => x.Ratings.Any(y => y.MovieId == movieId)).ToList();
```

The inner [`.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<TP4_IFT501.UserRating>`. You're feeding the outer `.Where` the `IEnumerable` when it expects a boolean which is why you're getting the error.